# Why didn't Rama try to convince Vali, give a second chance before killing him

Tags: ramayana, rama, vali

*[Rama sends Angada to Ravana, to expostulate him and to bring him back to **reason**. Angada tries his best to convince Ravana, but in vain.](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga41/yuddha_41_frame.htm)* This, after knowing that Hanuma and Vibhishana tried doing the same and failed.

Why didn't Rama follow the same standard in Vali's case. Is it because he already promised Sugreeva that he would kill Vali? What is (if there is) Rama's standard for sparing or punishing your enemy?

Comment: I think Sugriva had already exhausted peaceful resolutions with Vali.

Comment: Vali din't have any reason to give away something to Sugriva. On behalf of Sugriva, had Rama tried the negotiations then not only the fight between brothers would have converted to Vali-Rama fight but Vali would have seen enemy in Rama and could have possibly possessed his half of the strength. Just a thought.

Comment: @iammilind I don't think the notion of Vali being able to take half his opponent's strength has any basis in Hindu scripture.

Comment: I came across [this blog post](http://jayasreesaranathan.blogspot.com/2012/03/crow-crime-and-ramas-reasons.html) while I was researching on _Why did Rama use Brahmaasthra on a crow?_ and it explains a bit of Rama's *danda neethi*.

Comment: Namaste This episode of Lord Rama & Vaali in Ramayana is a contentious issue, unexplained satisfactory by many learned persons. While there are many versions of answers to this instance, yet they all fall short of universal acceptance.

Comment: I just realized this a dup. of [Why did Lord Rama give a second chance to Ravan, but not to Vali?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/342/why-did-lord-rama-give-a-second-chance-to-ravan-but-not-to-vali)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of differences in both the cases
But in the end Dharma is the seed for any/all of Rama's decisions.

Please think along the following lines:

Case 1: Vali and Sugreeva -
Vali and Sugreeva are own brothers.

Vali did ill things to Sugreeva in an unprovoked manner.

Vali was not any stranger to Sugreeva (which is the case with Ravana and Rama). He lusted for his own brother's wife.

And not just that - a brother also snatching all the material, emotional and social belongings of his own brother is in itself a crime.

So, the water had reached well above the nose - and hence it was a clear decision to make there.

Case 2- On Ravana and Rama

Ravana was a stranger, equally established, devotee and powerful emperor as was Rama.

Ravana might have been provoked by what was done to his sister.

Ravana was a mighty king himself and hence Rama spared him a chance to get educated...

And before sending Angada - Hanuma was sent to assess the strength of Ravana.
And according to Hanuma - Ravana has not touched Sita at all - and he was willing to wait till Sita accepts him, by all means.

Had Rama approached Vali - he could have got Sita very easily, as Ravana got defeated by Vali.

But Rama chose Dharma and hence chose Sugreeva for help.

Comment: @@Sanjana - Vaali and Ravana became friends and both had taken a solemn vow like Raama and Sugriva, to protect each other's kingdoms. Had Raama approached Vaali for Searching Sita, there is also a possibility that he would have sided with Ravana.

Comment: "_Hanuma was sent to assess the strength of Ravana_" - If I recollect correctly, Hanuma was sent to find Sita but in the process decides to have a dialogue with Ravana and convince him to return Sita; also tells him not to pick up a fight with the great Rama. Ravana doesn't listen, instead wants Hanuma killed. This is what I was referring to in the question - that Hanuma already tried his hand negotiating (...well not exactly negotiating because you don't kill a few kith & kin of your enemy before sit down to negotiate and offer advice!)

Comment: @Krishna I think Vali says to Rama when he's dying that if Rama had made friends with him rather than with Sugriva, Vali would have immediately defeated Ravana and rescued Sita.

Comment: @Keshav - Yes, i know that.  it is statement of a dying man in death pain who is out of senses. But, you conveniently forget that Vaali and Ravana had forged friendship similar to Raama and Sugriva

Comment: @Keshav - Moreover, hypothetically, let us assume Raama approached Vaali for help. Due to solemn friendship between Vaali and Ravana, even if vaali approached Ravana for release of Goddess Sita, there is high possibility Vaali would be forced to side with Ravana, because they had vowed that they will consider each others kingdom as their own kingdom.

Comment: @Keshav - Vali defeating Ravana when he was alone is different scenario. Even, if Vaali tries to fight Ravana, in Lanka, Ravana is almost unsurmountable because he would be supported by Indrajit and all other super powerful rakshasas like Atikaya etc. Also, remember, Kumbhakarna who didnt even feel a pinch when hit by arrows of Raama which were similar to the one that killed Vaali in one go. Kumbhakarna would have gobbled Vaali and destroyed him like a mere insect.

Comment: @Sanjana I am in no means efficient to give you any knowledge. But please kindly allow me to tell you this- 'There are a lot of differences' should actually be written as - 'There **is** a lot of differences'. Please note this- the '*is*' in your sentence is connected to '**a lot**', not to '***differences***', so it should not be 'are'. Had your sentence been this- 'There are '**lots**' of differences', then 'are' should be used. Thank you to allow me to tell you, who are much greater than me, this common English mistake. 