# Shudra doing Tapas

Tags: kali-yuga, shudra, tapasya

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/why-did-r%C4%81ma-kill-%C5%9Aamb%C5%ABka-and-is-r%C4%81ma-justified-in-killing-him-without-a-second?r=SearchResults),
SRSTIKHANDA of Padma Purana says:

> Shudras are not entitled to do penance in all the three yugas, except the Kali Yuga.

Does it mean Shudras are allowed to penance in Kali Yuga?

Shudras are not allowed to chant mantras. So how they do penance?

Isn't Jabala in Treta yuga was Shudra?

Comment: Shudras are allowed to chant mantras like those mentioned in Tantras. Only Vedic mantras they are not allowed to chant. The verse you quoted clearly says that Shudras are allowed to do penance in Kali. Also note, penance (Tapas) is not limited to mantra japa. Fasting, for example, is also a form of Tapas.

Comment: @Rickross So Tapas has many meanings right? So Sudras in Dwapar Yuga chanted Tantrik Mantras and did meditation on God's form and also done fasting so all these come under "Tapas"? I mean different Tapas...Not kind of conquering the World etc

Comment: Yes, during mantra initiation lot of restraints are to be followed. So it's a kind of Tapas only. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru